# I get this error when i run the fastAPI code

Tags: python, fastapi

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
app = FastAPI()
@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}
```

this is code i am trying to run and when i run this command `uvicorn main:app` in my command prompt i get this error

```
(venv) C:\Users\Saad Mohammed\Documents\FastAPI>uvicorn main:app
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Saad Mohammed\Documents\FastAPI\venv\Scripts\uvicorn.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\users\saad mohammed\documents\fastapi\venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1128, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\saad mohammed\documents\fastapi\venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1053, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "c:\users\saad mohammed\documents\fastapi\venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1395, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "c:\users\saad mohammed\documents\fastapi\venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 754, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\saad mohammed\documents\fastapi\venv\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\main.py", line 425, in main
    run(app, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\saad mohammed\documents\fastapi\venv\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\main.py", line 447, in run
    server.run()
  File "c:\users\saad mohammed\documents\fastapi\venv\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\server.py", line 68, in run
    return asyncio.run(self.serve(sockets=sockets))
  File "C:\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "C:\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 642, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "c:\users\saad mohammed\documents\fastapi\venv\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\server.py", line 76, in serve
    config.load()
  File "c:\users\saad mohammed\documents\fastapi\venv\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\config.py", line 448, in load
    self.loaded_app = import_from_string(self.app)
  File "c:\users\saad mohammed\documents\fastapi\venv\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\importer.py", line 21, in import_from_string
    module = importlib.import_module(module_str)
  File "C:\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File ".\main.py", line 4, in <module>
    @app.get("/")
TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'path'
```

how do i remove this error i am very new to this

Comment: Where do you want to deploy your code? on some platforms like Heroku you can't use `uvicorn` becuase it uses `gunicorn`. so you need to add a `uvicorn` worker to `gunicorn` then it works!

Comment: visual studio code

Comment: I guess your project is configured wrong. double check it. I created a FastAPI project in pycharm and test your codes. everything is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Your original code is fine, runs perfectly. I used pycharm on a virtual environment. Try these small changes:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/root")
 def root():
   return {"message": "Hello World"}
```

If it still doesn't work, you might need to set up a virtual environment like python venv for example, if you haven't done so already.

Comment: What "*small*" changes? Changing `async def` to just `def`? The OP's code is the same code from the FastAPI tutorial: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/first-steps/#first-steps. So async _should_ work and error is coming from somewhere else.

Comment: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/async/#in-a-hurry.   Thats the "small" change I was suggesting. There are a few issues related to particular IDEs. Yes it should run with async but best practise in this case is not to use it unless if he was waiting for a response from a db.

Comment: Again if you check his error message, it clearly says he is missing a 'path' argument. That's the other 'small' change I suggested. This is a problem I once came across but on pycharm.

Comment: i did set up virtual environment for fastAPI and i am using python.exe that was the interpreter that was inside the virtual environment script

Comment: Did you try to add a 'path' to your decorator? Your error seems to ask for it though I know you have "/". I suggested "/root"

Comment: okay i will try

Comment: okay "/root" makes the code run but when it opens the url instead of "hello world" i get detail:"not found" what to do

Comment: ok, now you need to use your swagger ui. on you browser use http://127.0.0.1/docs and that should give you your swagger. If you just want to see your response without going to swagger, type http://127.0.0.1/root

Comment: okay so do i have to do this everytime like is this error common or is it because some where the installation went wrong in my system

Comment: i think it's something to do with some IDEs, I know pycharm does that. I have tried to research on it but so far I have turned up with nothing. Does your api work with these small changes though?